# How can I access subclass method from Arraylist of Superclass?

Tags: java, methods, casting, subclass, getter

I have a Animal super class. It has Rabbit and Donkey sub classes. To print list of Donkeys and their attributes I need to call getter methods of Donkey but since I have Arraylist of Animals in my main class, I can't reach my Donkey's subclass getters. In this case I tried explicit type casting but is it true approach or it will be problematic later?

Here is the code:

```
public void listDonkey() {
    int i;
    for(i=0 ; i<animals.size() ; i++) {//loop to show all Donkeys
        if (animals.get(i).getClass() == Donkey.class) {// check te type is Donkey or Rabbit
            //so here is it okay to do type casting by typing Donkey ?
            System.out.println("\nDonkey weight: " + ((Donkey)animals.get(i)).getDonkeyWeight()
            );
        }
    }
```

Can you explain me the true way of doing this?

Comment: That is not how you do polymorphism.  You need to add a method to override to print the animals attributes, like toString() or similar

Comment: Indeed -- rethink the whole inheritance structure and try to figure out behaviors that all types will need, such as perhaps `printList()` and have those methods declared in the parent class.

Comment: Actually, I have some common behaviors, and the common getters and setters are declared in the superclass, which I can call. But I am trying to understand how to use only subclass-specific methods with this supper class ArrayList. Is it possible without typecasting?

Comment: No because animals are not donkeys, but donkeys are animals.

Comment: So is it impossible to reach any method of the Donkey subclass for the elements of the ArrayList of Animal superclass?

Comment: It's possible with either instanceof check and casting or using the visitor design pattern to mimic double-dispatch, but better always is to avoid having to do this, and I am 90% certain that your assignment does not need these kludges and can be solved without using them. Again, focus on a design that does not require these.

Comment: If you're going to check the instance, I recommend using `if (animals.get(i) instanceof Donkey d) { ...` (assuming you're using Java 16 or higher), or `if (animals.get(i) instanceof Donkey) { Donkey d = (Donkey) animals.get(i); ...`, not `if (animals.get(i).getClass() == Donkey.class)`...